# How to implement a Cube 2: Sauerbraten octree?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

I found this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_2:_Sauerbraten#/media/File:Sauer_editing-1--.png) of subdividing a cube based on octree model for the game "Cube 2: Sauerbraten octree". How can such an octree subdivision algorithm can be implemented?

I also need a generalized version of this which can be applicable for any rectangular cuboid having different length, width and height.

How can this be done?

**Edit 1:**

Consider a volume as

```
vol = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRbrain"}];
```

I can partition it in the following way:

```
{w, d, h} = ImageDimensions[vol];

Manipulate[ImagePartition[vol, {w/np, d/np, h/np}], {np, 1, 10, 1}]
```

This gives me a list of all the subvolumes. However, I cannot do the partition into the higher levels and display the partitions in the way as displayed in the mathematica demonstration or in the wikipedia image.

Edit 2:

```
ImageAssemble[
 ImagePartition[vol, {w/2, d/2, h/2}] /. 
  i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 20, 0]];
```

This gives me

[image]

I can break one subpart as

```
ImageAssemble[
 ImagePartition[
   ImagePartition[vol, {w/2, d/2, h/2}][[1, 1, 2]], {w/4, d/4, 
    h/4}] /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 20, 0]]
```

And the corresponding result is:

[image]

I am still trying to figure it out how to assemble the second one replacing the corresponding part in the first image.

**Edit 2:**

Now I can split the volume at the second level.

```
temp = vol;
{w, d, h} = ImageDimensions[temp];
temp1 = ImagePartition[temp, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
temp2 = temp1[[1, 1, 2]];
temp3 = ImagePartition[temp2, {Floor[w/4], Floor[d/4], Floor[h/4]}];
temp3reconstructed = 
  ImageAssemble[temp3 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]];
temp1[[1, 1, 2]] = 
  ImageResize[
   temp3reconstructed, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
temp1reconstructed = 
 ImageAssemble[temp1 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]]
```

and the output is:

[image]

Comment: @Kuba I have looked into the quadTree implementation (http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QuadtreeSubdivision/) and this wikipedia pages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_2:_Sauerbraten)

Comment: @Kuba The quadTree implementation only works for square images.

Comment: Have you tried implementing anything, or do you want us to write the whole thing for you and give you the code?

Comment: @Rahul See my edit. This is what I have done so far and I am still trying to progress further. Whenever I reach up to anything, I will update.