# How to implement recurrence operations efficiently?

Tags: iterators, procedural-programming

This question is related to this [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164745/how-to-implement-a-cube-2-sauerbraten-octree?noredirect=1#comment435864_164745). I basically want to partition a volume recursively.

Consider a volume as

```
vol = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRbrain"}];
```

Now,

```
temp = vol;
```

If I do this,

```
{w, d, h} = ImageDimensions[temp];
partition1 = 
  ImagePartition[temp, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
reconstruction1 = 
 ImageAssemble[partition1 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]]
```

This gives me first level of partitions.

If I do the following

```
{w, d, h} = ImageDimensions[temp];
partition1 = 
  ImagePartition[temp, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
selection1 = partition1[[1, 1, 2]];
partition2 = 
  ImagePartition[selection1, {Floor[w/4], Floor[d/4], Floor[h/4]}];
reconstruction2 = 
  ImageAssemble[partition2 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]];
partition1[[1, 1, 2]] = 
  ImageResize[reconstruction2, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
reconstruction1 = 
 ImageAssemble[partition1 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]]
```

I get second level splitting.

```
{w, d, h} = ImageDimensions[temp];
partition1 = 
  ImagePartition[temp, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
selection1 = partition1[[1, 1, 2]];
partition2 = 
  ImagePartition[selection1, {Floor[w/4], Floor[d/4], Floor[h/4]}];
selection2 = partition2[[1, 1, 2]];
partition3 = 
  ImagePartition[selection2, {Floor[w/8], Floor[d/8], Floor[h/8]}];
reconstruction3 = 
  ImageAssemble[partition3 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]];
partition2[[1, 1, 2]] = 
  ImageResize[reconstruction3, {Floor[w/4], Floor[d/4], Floor[h/4]}];
reconstruction2 = 
  ImageAssemble[partition2 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]];
partition1[[1, 1, 2]] = 
  ImageResize[reconstruction2, {Floor[w/2], Floor[d/2], Floor[h/2]}];
reconstruction1 = 
 ImageAssemble[partition1 /. i_Image3D :> ImagePad[i, 5, 0]]
```

And the above code snippet gives me third level splitting.

How can I make this process iterative in an efficient way so that I can set the `level` as a parameter and get the final result after how many iterations I wish?

Answer (score 1):

You could to that by defining a function that splits a single image into 8 ones, make it `Listable`.

```
ClearAll[splitImage];
SetAttributes[splitImage, Listable]
splitImage[temp_Image3D] := 
  Map[
   i \[Function] ImagePad[i, 5, 0], 
   ImagePartition[temp, Floor[ImageDimensions[temp]/2]], 
    {3}
  ];
```

Afterwards, you can use `Nest`.

```
iterations = 3;
result = Nest[splitImage, vol, iterations];
```

Comment: How can you reassemble them at every level as is done in my code?

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of an issue. Functions that act in images behave a bit different than those acting on arrays, so I gave up at some point. For level 2, the following worked: `result = Nest[splitImage, vol, 2];
ImageAssemble[
 ArrayReshape[
  Transpose[result, Join[2 Range[3] - 1, 2 Range[3]]],
  ConstantArray[2^2, 3]
  ]
 ]` Maybe you are able to generalize it yourself. The problem is finding the right second argument to `Transpose`...